# How to stop an infinite loop on the outside?

Tags: python

Consider the situation: i have the class(third-party library) with method that used infinity loop:

```
class Worker(object):
    ...
    def transator(self):
       ...
       #if connected print data 
       while self.connected:
           ...  
           print data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    worker = Worker()
    worker.translator()
```

I use this class in my program and can not be changed. ( I looked code on github :) ).
What the best method to stop this method manually ? I need change self.connected to False outside this method. I have an idea, but I think it's very complicated.

```
import time
from threading import Thread 

class Terminator(Worker):
     ... 
     def terminate(self):
         time.sleep(10)
         self.connected = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ter = Terminator()
    t   = Tread(target=ter.terminate)
    t.start()
    ter.translator()
```

Are there other ways?

Comment: I can't really follow you, or i just did misunderstand what you meant. The code you depend on is on github and you can't fork and modify it? I'm puzzled!

Comment: @DonQuestion I thought about it, but the code changes will be more difficult than my program :) It twython library for streaming twitter api. Method user() is infinity loop, all working correct, but i can't do anything else. I thought maybe i don't understand basis

Comment: @DonQuestion https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/streaming/api.py  main class |||| https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/streaming/types.py add-on classes ( user method inside ) |||  https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/examples/stream.py example

Comment: @DonQuestion TwythonStreamerTypes.user() used  TwythonStreamer._request() . _request method used infinity loop. I don ' t understand how i should use user() method . I can run and stop it with KeyboardInterrupt and all.

Comment: @Sultanov: mgilson pointed out, that the Worker-"instructor" does have a timeout-parameter, which is by default set to an unreasonable high number of 300 seconds! Just change it! ;-) If you don't want to relay on a timeout, then i gave you an pointer to an alternatively solution if you neither want a timeout, nor subclassing, nor a fork.

Answer (score 2):

> Q: "How to stop an infinite loop on the outside"
>
> A: Read the documentation for the method/class which is using the infinite loop and look to see if there are any parameters which influence how it runs.

For your use case, it looks to me like you should just be able to pass the [timeout](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/blob/master/twython/streaming/api.py#L35) parameter to the `TwythonStreamer` constructor...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I experimented with this argument: if it is small (5, 10, 15, 20) raises the exception «««SSLError: The read operation timed out »»» . If it 50 or more - infinity loop.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to mcgilson correct answer you could add a property-descriptor like:

```
def toggle_connect(self, singleton=[True]):
    singleton[0] = not singleton[0]
    return singleton

and after:

worker=Worker()
Worker.connected = property(toggle_connect)
```

Comment: thx for your help,I will study your way, it is very innovative

Comment: It's just a starting point, but maybe it's already all you need. Depends on what you are trying to do! If it is, then pls don't hasten to accept my answer, or mgilson's depending which suits you more! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like the following:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = Worker()
    t = Thread(target=w.transator)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    w.connected = False
    t.join()
```

Comment: I think the fact that this version doesn't create a child class makes it cleaner.  Threading is the only approach that will work here anyway, so I think it is either this or what the OP has.  With this simple example there are definitely not any complications caused by not having locking.

Comment: Well threading would be the LAST thing i would consider. The word alone gives me ulcers and headaches! ;-) Subclassing, monkey-patching, using the descriptor-protocoll, even a brute - forced - but managed exception, all that but pls no THREADING.... ahhhhhhh ;-)

Comment: @F.J This version is cleaner and will help me in the future for other programs. But I would like to learn other methods, if they exist.

Comment: @DonQuestion Not sure how monkey-patching or descriptors solve the problem.  In your answer the `connected` property is toggled on each access, which seems very different to me than manually changing the `connected` property to False, which is what the question is asking for.  If you need logic outside of the class determining when to change that property, it is going to have to be threads because with a single thread you will just be stuck in the loop.

Comment: Of course mgilson's approach (if OP can get it to work) is best, if the library provides a way to do this that is what you should use.

Comment: @DonQuestion Yeah I wasn't seeing at first how your method could be used to stop it manually or after some amount of time has elapsed but I get it now.  I do agree that threading should be avoided where possible, but the way the problem was framed I just wasn't seeing any other way to do it.